# Groovy XML Holder returns null for unformatted xml

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, soapui

I am retrieving xml tag using xmlholder but it's not working with unformatted xml.

```
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder(mockRequest.requestContent);
holder.declareNamespace("ns2", "http://example.com")

if(holder.getNodeValue('//ns2:GetCustomerInfo')!=null){
println true
}
```

I am getting true for formatted xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <S:Header>
   </S:Header>
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:GetCustomerInfo xmlns:ns2="http://example.com">
         <ns2:Identifier>4111119876543210</ns2:Identifier>
      </ns2:GetCustomerInfo>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I am not getting true if xml is unformatted and given as one line string.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><S:Header></S:Header><S:Body><ns2:GetCustomerInfo xmlns:ns2="http://example.com"><ns2:Identifier>4111119876543210</ns2:Identifier></ns2:GetCustomerInfo></S:Body></S:Envelope>
```

Actually I need to retrieve value from unformatted xml as I am going to get data as unformatted.

Comment: Your "unformatted" XML contains `xmlns:ns2="http://test.com"`. Your code sample above works with a different namespace URI.

Comment: Thanks Tomalak, I tried by changing the namespace but still it didn't work with unformatted xml. Unformatted xml request I am going to get from JAVA SOAP WS and above groovy code is written in soap ui simulator. Is there a way so that I can format xml before using it with Groovy Xml Holder.

Comment: The "unformatted" thing is a red herring, simply forget it. XML source layout has *zero* impact on XPath. If `'//ns2:GetCustomerInfo'` does not return any nodes, that plain and simple means there are no `<ns2:GetCustomerInfo>` in your document. Either because they are really not there, or because you have a namespace URI mismatch. There are no other possibilities.

Comment: @Tomalak Thanks again. I have updated question. Actually I have completed removed redudent namespace and tried but still it works only with formatted xml and not with unformatted xml. Please check updated question.

Comment: What do you get when you query for `//*`?

Comment: Well, you have no XML document. Maybe there is a parse error, are you checking for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working as expected!

1. In, what you are calling, the "formatted case" the **value** of the node
   `GetCustomerInfo` is a newline character and some whitespace, and so it is not `null`.
2. In your "unformatted case", the **value** of the node
   `GetCustomerInfo` is nothing, and so it is `null`.

To prove this, you can insert a single space character in the unformatted string after the `GetCustomerInfo` node, and run your test again.

You might want to try using `getDomNode()` instead of `getNodeValue()` to get the behaviour you are looking for.